# bootstrap 4: Placing a image between two card blocks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

On the bootstrap 4 card documentation page(Under Images > Image Caps), they have provided two examples. The image can either be placed on the top or bottom of the card block with the .card-block div following or preceding the image tag.
I was wondering if it is possible to place the image between two card blocks like so.

```
<div class="card-group> 
    <div class="card>
        <div class="card-block></div>
        <img src="..." alt="..." >
        <div class="card-block></div>
    </div>
    <!--Multiple Cards-->
</div>
```

I tried doing it but the result is not as expected. Although the cards do have the same height and width, the images don't align correctly(with respect to the images in other cards). Depending on the content of the card block, the image will either shift up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a card-block for the top content, use a card-header instead.

```
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"> </div>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="card-block"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C4Zz.png)